# How to extract single-/multiline regex-matching items from an unpredictably formatted file and put each one in a single line into output file?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, replace, grep

I have a **very huge** file which looks like this:

```
<a>text</a>text
blah


<b>data1</b>abc<b>data2</b>    
  <b>data3</b>blahblah
    <c>text</c>
  <d>text</d>
<x>blahblah<b>data4   
   data5


        data6</b>  
    <b>data7
</x>
```

That is, its formatting is unpredictable. I need to extract each `<b>...</b>` item (it might contain multiline text!) and put every one of them in a single separate line. At the same time, I need to replace newlines and spaces with a single space.

Desired output:

```
<b>data1</b>
<b>data2</b>
<b>data3</b>
<b>data4 data5 data6</b>
```

All I've found is two-steps-long way:

```
gawk '{if ($0 != "") { printf "%s", gensub(/\s+/, " ", "g", gensub(/\s+$/, "", "g", $0)) } }' path/to/input.txt > path/to/single-line.txt
```

and then

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)<b>.*?</b>' path/to/single-line.txt > path/to/output.txt
```

But I don't like it! Having to convert a multiGB text file to a single line... does not seem to be nice. Is it possible to solve such a problem in a single pass, “on the fly”?

Comment: python+beautifulsoup is best approach

Comment: Is your source file well formed XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your document is well-formed, i.e. `<b>` opening tags always match with a `</b>` closing tag, then this may be what you need:

```
sed 's@<[/]\?b>@\n&\n@g' path/to/input.txt | 
awk 'BEGIN {buf=""}
   /<b>/ {Y=1; buf=""}
   /<\/b>/ {Y=0; print buf"</b>"}
   Y {buf = buf$0}
' | tr -s ' '
```

Output:

```
<b>data1</b>
<b>data2</b>
<b>data3</b>
<b>data4 data5 data6</b>
```

Explanation:

We first use `sed 's@<[/]\?b>@\n&\n@g'` to move `<b>` and `</b>` into their own line.

Then we implement a simple parser with awk:

- `BEGIN {buf=""}` : initialize a buffer
- `/<b>/ {Y=1; buf=""}`: when `<b>` is found, enable capturing (Y=1) and empty the buffer
- `/<\/b>/ {Y=0; print buf"</b>"}` : when `</b>` is found, disable capturing and print the buffer contents along with the closing tag
- `Y {buf = buf$0}` : If the capturing flag is true, append the current line to the buffer

Finally we pass the output through `tr -s ' '` to squeeze multiple-spaces into single-space.

If you want it in one-line:

```
sed 's@<[/]\?b>@\n&\n@g' in.txt | awk 'BEGIN{B=""} /<b>/{Y=1;B=""} /<\/b>/{Y=0;print B"</b>"} Y{B=B$0}' | tr -s ' '
```

or save it as a shell script (`extract_b.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
sed 's@<[/]\?b>@\n&\n@g' "$1" | awk 'BEGIN{B=""} /<b>/{Y=1;B=""} /<\/b>/{Y=0;print B"</b>"} Y{B=B$0}' | tr -s ' '
```

and use it like this:

```
extract_b.sh path/to/input.txt > /path/to/output.txt
```

*Also tested with `mawk` which is much faster (27 Mb/s vs. 17Mb/s in my tests) and you may prefer using it for your multiGB file.*

Comment: Thank you, I am going to test this, but I have one thing to ask: in your one-line version, you specified `in.txt`. Does that mean the name of the input file? If yes, how to specify the name of an output file? Just change `in.txt` to `input.txt > output.txt`?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, that sed expression does not look clear to me... What exactly is it doing? What if I want to extract items matching `[start]` and `<end>` regexes (yes, exactly like this), how do I modify a `sed` part?

Comment: Yes, `in.txt` is the input file. In order to save the results to an output file, you have to add a redirection `> output.txt` at the end of the command. i.e. `sed 's@<[/]\?b>@\n&\n@g' in.txt | awk 'BEGIN{B=""} /<b>/{Y=1;B=""} /<\/b>/{Y=0;print B"</b>"} Y{B=B$0}' | tr -s ' ' > output.txt`. The same applies to any command, not only this one.

Comment: The regex in `sed` matches occurrences of `<b>` or `</b>`  (`<[/]\?b>`) and prepends and appends a new line `\n` to them (`\n&\n`). This way, it moves these tags to their own line. This simplifies the implementation of the `awk` parser. The `@` symbols you see in the regex are just separators which are preferred in this case from the default slashes `/`. i.e. instead of using the format `sed 's/pattern/replacement/g'` we use the format  `sed 's@pattern@replacement@g'`. The reason is that the pattern string already contains slashes `/` and with this trick we don't need to escape them.

Comment: If you want to match `[start]` and `<end>` instead of `<b>` and `</b>`, you have to change the sed expression like this: `sed -e 's/\[start\]/\n&\n/g' -e 's/<end>/\n&\n/g'`. In this case you don't have to use other symbols as separators because `[start]` and `<end>` do not contain slashes. But it would be exactly the same if you used:  `sed -e 's@\[start\]@\n&\n@g' -e 's@<end>@\n&\n@g'`. Of course you'll need to change the `awk` part as well: `/<b>/` changed to `/\[start\]/` (escaping `[]` since they have special meaning in regex) and `/<\/b>/`changed to `/<end>/`

Comment: All together: You have to change the compact version to:  
`sed -e 's/\[start\]/\n&\n/g' -e 's/<end>/\n&\n/g' in.txt | awk 'BEGIN{B=""} /\[start\]/{Y=1;B=""} /<end>/{Y=0;print B"<end>"} Y{B=B$0}' | tr -s ' ' > output.txt`

Comment: Thank you, really. I tested this, and this seems to work as expected! I didn't test it with multiGB-sized input though. What about memory consumption, can you predict if this won't eat too much memory?

Comment: Don't worry about memory consumption. It keeps constant (nearly zero <3MB) either the input file is a few MBs or several TBs. This is the nice thing with pipe programming in unix/linux. The commands are buffering a small part of the data each time and pass the result to next command-line in the chain (This is not true for some commands which need to load the whole file in advance like `sort` or `column -t`). In my tests in a 5-year old 1st-gen i7-cpu, this script achieves 27MB/s with `mawk`, taking ~30secs to process a 0.8GB file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption that your source file is XML - it looks like it.
If it is, then pretty fundamentally, regex based parsing doesn't work very well - semantically identical XML will match different patterns.

So I would suggest the tool for the job here is an XML parser. I'd approach it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'b' => sub { print $_ ->text_only =~ s/\s+/ /grs, "\n"; }
    }
)->parse( <> );
```

This will run through your source data, and print the `b` elements as you go.

But the problem of memory footprint is a bit of a bigger one. XML takes about 10x memory, which is ... bad news really. Fortunately, with `XML::Twig` you can handle that case as well by using the `purge` method:

```
    '_default_' => sub { $_[0] -> purge; }
```

This sets a handler on every element (that isn't a `b`) and will purge your in memory data so far.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'b' => sub { print $_ ->text_only =~ s/\s+/ /grs, "\n"; }
         '_default_' => sub { $_[0] -> purge; }
    }
)->parse( <> );
```

Run it with `./myscript.pl <yourfile>`.

You can expand it for clarity if you prefer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub handle_b {
    my ( $twig, $b_element ) = @_; 
    my $b_text = $b_element -> text_only;
    $b_text =~ s/\s+/ /gs; #replace multiline space with single space. 
    print $b_text,"\n"; 
}

sub purge_as_we_go {
    my ( $twig, $element ) = @_; 
    $twig -> purge; 
}

XML::Twig->new(
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'b' => \&handle_b,
        '_default_' => \&purge_as_we_go,
    }
)->parse( <> );
```

We make use of the diamond operator `<>` which has a special meaning in perl - it is *either* data piped on `STDIN` (so we can `cat XMLFILE | ./myscript.pl`) or it's opening files supplied on command line and reading those (`./myscript.pl some_xml_file`.

This is similar to how most unix tools work, but obviously if you prefer you can either `parse ( <STDIN> );` or `parsefile ( $ARGV[0] );`

Edit: Just spotted you're after the tag as well - in which case you can use `$element -> sprint` to give the element/attributes etc. instead of `text_only`.
Note though - this might not work particularly well for nested elements.

Comment: The input file doesn't **have** to be XML. I just want to copy matches - from first regex, to second regex.

Comment: Perl also has the range operator, that may also help. But for structured data something that is structure aware is generally a good idea.

Comment: You already have an awk solution, so unless you really want a perl solution I'll leave it. But I'll point out - perl is not really any more complicated than awk, and often less so.